# Is there a way to export aliases in macOS in the Korn Shell (ksh)?

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, darwin

Earlier versions of the Korn shell (`ksh`) allowed aliases to be exported to subshells by using the `-x` option, for example:

```
alias -x dog=cat
```

With the current version of macOS the `ksh` man page says:

```
"The obsolete -x option has no effect."
```

Is there an alternate way to export aliases in macOS in `ksh` without putting them in `.kshrc`?

Comment: How are you defining them in the first place, other than in $ENV (~/.kshrc by default) ?  The -x option to alias was removed back in 93g (default in macOS is 93u+) according to the RELEASE93 file.  (note to mods... this isn't macOS-specific and probably should be moved).

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, put idempotent things (e.g., setting the `PATH` environment variable) in `~/.profile`, but put things that must be performed on a per-shell/subshell basis (e.g., aliases; `HISTFILE` and `ENV` and `PS1` environment variables) in `~/.kshrc` (or whatever your `${ENV}` is set as in `~/.profile`).  Then you will have your aliases proper set afresh in each subshell of ksh.

**~/.profile**

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]
    then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]
        then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
        fi
elif [ -n "$KSH_VERSION" ]
    then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.kshrc" ]
        then
        . "$HOME/.kshrc"
        fi
elif [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]
    then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.zshrc" ]
        then
        . "$HOME/.zshrc"
        fi
    fi
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]
    then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    fi
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ]
    then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
    fi
```

**~/.kshrc**

```
hostname=/bin/hostname
ksh=/bin/ksh
stty=/bin/stty
tput=/usr/bin/tput
tty=/usr/bin/tty
whoami=whoami
bold=$(${tput}      bold)
dim=$(${tput}       dim)
bgblue=$(${tput}    setab 4)
bgcyan=$(${tput}    setab 6)
bggreen=$(${tput}   setab 2)
bgmagenta=$(${tput} setab 5)
bgred=$(${tput}     setab 1)
bgwhite=$(${tput}   setab 7)
bgyellow=$(${tput}  setab 3)
fgblue=$(${tput}    setaf 4)
fgcyan=$(${tput}    setaf 6)
fggreen=$(${tput}   setaf 2)
fgmagenta=$(${tput} setaf 5)
fgred=$(${tput}     setaf 1)
fgwhite=$(${tput}   setaf 7)
fgyellow=$(${tput}  setaf 3)
sgr0=$(${tput}      sgr0)
smso=$(${tput}      smso)
smul=$(${tput}      smul)
rmso=$(${tput}      rmso)
rmul=$(${tput}      rmul)
tty_path=$(${tty})
set -o emacs
export PS1='${fgblack}${bgyellow}↑$
${sgr0}ksh${dim}${fgblue}${bggreen}$(${hostname})${sgr0}${fgwhite}${tty_path#/dev/}${sgr0}${smul}${dim}$(${whoami})${sgr0}${PWD}
$ '
export ENV=~/.kshrc
alias l='ls -AFq'
alias rd='rmdir'
alias md='mkdir'
alias ssh='ssh -X'
alias emacs-nw='emacs -nw'
alias over='_(){ cd ../$1; }; _'
alias cd..='_(){ cd ../$1; }; _'
```

This best practice is true of shells other than ksh as well, such as csh and bash and zsh.

(Most especially don't put incremental/nonidempotent appending or prepending of `PATH` environment variable in `~/.kshrc`, but that is unrelated per se to the question here.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not much of a `ksh` user so some other users will probably be able to improve on this answer. (Or disapprove.)

While I have not found how to export aliases, I have found how to save the aliases to an exported variable. The script in the `.kshrc` file can be modified to recreate the aliases stored in this variable. The proposed commands to add to the `.kshrc` file are shown below

```
if [[ ${#LISTOFALIASES} != 0 ]]; then
    ALIASIFSBACKUP="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    while read -r CURRENTALIAS; do
        eval "command -p alias $CURRENTALIAS"
    done <<< "$LISTOFALIASES"
    IFS="$ALIASIFSBACKUP"
    unset ALIASIFSBACKUP CURRENTALIAS
fi
export LISTOFALIASES
aliasx() { command -p alias "$@"; LISTOFALIASES="$(command -p alias)"; }
unaliasx() { command -p unalias "$@"; LISTOFALIASES="$(command -p alias)"; }
command -p alias alias=aliasx
command -p alias unalias=unaliasx
```